# Troubleshooting SMTP Error 504 When Sending Email with Attachment

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, codeigniter-4

Description: I encountered a 504 error when attempting to send an email with an attachment using SMTP over SSL (port 465). However, when sending emails without attachments or using a localhost setup, no errors occurred. I suspect the issue might be related to either my code or the server configuration. Can someone assist me in resolving this issue?

Background Research:

1. Checked SMTP server status to ensure it's operational.
2. Verified SSL/TLS certificate validity and installation.
3. Reviewed firewall settings to ensure outbound connections on port 465 are allowed.
4. Confirmed credentials used for SMTP authentication.
5. Checked attachment size to ensure it doesn't exceed server limits.
6. Reviewed code configuration for SMTP settings, including hostname, port, encryption method, and authentication.
7. Enabled debugging/logging in the code to capture detailed SMTP communication information.
8. Tested sending emails with attachments using different email clients or libraries.
9. Reviewed SMTP server logs for any error messages or warnings.
10. Considered using an alternate SMTP server to troubleshoot compatibility issues.

Question: Is the 504 error when sending emails with attachments via SMTP over SSL likely caused by issues with my code configuration or the server setup?

```
 public function send_email($to, $subject, $message, $from = null, $from_name = null, $attachment = null, $cc = null, $bcc = null)
{
    list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $to);
    if ('tecdiary.com' != $domain || DEMO) {
        $result = false;
        $this->load->library('tec_mail');
        try {
            $result = $this->tec_mail->send_mail($to, $subject, $message, $from, $from_name, $attachment, $cc, $bcc);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Mail Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage()); 
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

tec_mail

```
class Tec_mail
{
public function __construct()
{
}

public function __get($var)
{
    return get_instance()->$var;
}

public function send_mail($to, $subject, $body, $from = null, $from_name = null, $attachment = null, $cc = null, $bcc = null)
{
    // $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail          = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    try {
        
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Port     = 465;
        $mail->Username = '';
        $mail->Password = '';
            
        if (DEMO) {
            
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Port     = 465;
            $mail->Username = '';
            $mail->Password = '';

        // $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        } elseif ($this->Settings->protocol == 'mail') {
            $mail->isMail();
        } elseif ($this->Settings->protocol == 'sendmail') {
            $mail->isSendmail();
        } elseif ($this->Settings->protocol == 'smtp') {
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host       = $this->Settings->smtp_host;
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = !empty($this->Settings->smtp_crypto) ? $this->Settings->smtp_crypto : false;
            $mail->Port       = $this->Settings->smtp_port;
            if (isset($this->Settings->smtp_oauth2)) {
                $email        = $this->Settings->smtp_user;
                $clientId     = $this->config->item('client_id');
                $clientSecret = $this->config->item('client_secret');
                $refreshToken = $this->config->item('refresh_token');

                $this->mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

                $provider = new Google(['clientId' => $clientId, 'clientSecret' => $clientSecret]);

                $this->mail->setOAuth(new OAuth([
                    'provider'     => $provider,
                    'clientId'     => $clientId,
                    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
                    'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
                    'userName'     => $email,
                ]));
            } else {
                $mail->Username = $this->Settings->smtp_user;
                $mail->Password = $this->Settings->smtp_pass;
            }
        } else {
            $mail->isMail();
        }

        if ($from && $from_name) {
            $mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);
            $mail->addReplyTo($from, $from_name);
        } elseif ($from) {
            $mail->setFrom($from, $this->Settings->site_name);
            $mail->addReplyTo($from, $this->Settings->site_name);
        } else {
            $mail->setFrom($this->Settings->default_email, $this->Settings->site_name);
            $mail->addReplyTo($this->Settings->default_email, $this->Settings->site_name);
        }

        $mail->addAddress($to);
        if ($cc) {
            try {
                if (is_array($cc)) {
                    foreach ($cc as $cc_email) {
                        $mail->addCC($cc_email);
                    }
                } else {
                    $mail->addCC($cc);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                log_message('info', 'PHPMailer Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        if ($bcc) {
            try {
                if (is_array($bcc)) {
                    foreach ($bcc as $bcc_email) { 
                        $mail->addBCC($bcc_email);
                    }
                } else {
                    $mail->addBCC($bcc);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                log_message('info', 'PHPMailer Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($mail->Body);
        
        if ($attachment) { 
            if (is_array($attachment)) {
                foreach ($attachment as $attach) {
                    $mail->addAttachment($attach);
                }
            } else {
                $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
            }
        }

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            log_message('error', 'Mail Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
            throw new Exception($mail->ErrorInfo);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (MailException $e) {
        log_message('error', 'Mail Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception($e->errorMessage());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        log_message('error', 'Mail Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _"likely caused by issues with my code configuration or the server setup?"_ - if you use the same credentials to send a mail with an attachment of roughly the same size, using your own mail client - does that go through? Is there any more info on the 504, any error _text_ along with it?

Comment: nothing its just 504 error cloudflare but when i didn't include the attachment like its just the message it can send the email without any problem

Comment: As you haven't shared a single line of code, it's impossible to provide proper help

Comment: Also, why is this tagged with Laravel and CodeIgniter?

Comment: im using a codeigniter the laravel was just i think maybe somebody can help too

Comment: im sorry i can't share the code because its confidental

Comment: but maybe you can give me some suggestion?

Comment: Share your code if you want other to check it for problems. Also, please don't use any tag that is not related to your problem

Comment: ok i already add the code

Comment: Please also share the full and exact error message